# Overwriting Backbone.sync for socket.io

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, socket.io

Im working on a socket.io based server/client connection instead of ajax.
Client uses Backbone and I overwritten the Backbone.sync function with one 
*half assed* of my own:

```
  Backbone.sync = function (method, collection, options) {
    // use the window.io variable that was attached on init 
    var socket = window.io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    // emit the collection/model data with standard ajax method names and options
    socket.emit(method,{collection:collection.name,url:collection.url});
    // create a model in the collection for each frame coming in through that connection 
    socket.on(collection.url,function(socket_frame){
      collection.create(socket_frame['model']);
    })
  };
```

Instead of ajax calls I simply emit through socket attached to window.io
global var. Server listens to those emits and based on the model url, I don't want to change that behaviour and I use the default crud method names (read,patch...) inside each emited frame. The logic behind it (its a bit far thought, but who knows) that in case the client doesn't support Websockets I can easily fallback to default jQuery ajax. I attached the orginal Backbone.sync to a var so I can pass the same arguments to it when no websocket is available.

All it that greatness behalves properly and the server answers to the client events. The server emits then each model data as a seperate websocket frames in one connection.
I see the frames in the Network/Websocket filter as one (concurrent/established) connection 
and things seems to be working

Currently the function assumes I pass a collection and not a model.

**Questions:**

- Is that approach ok with you?
- How can I use the socket.io callbacks on 'success' and 'failure' etc in Backbone the right way so I don't have to call the collection.create function 'by-hand'?
- Is it better to establish different concurrent connections for models/collections or use the one already established instead?

Comment: You can check my implementation of `Backbone.sync` and `socket.io` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14199835/1282674 ... I'm using it, but it doesn't fall back to no websocket mode. Actually I think this is kind of `socket.io` problem, that is actually solved with SWF, but indeed it is a good fallback idea from you!

Comment: Well, using the same methods without changing the logic but just 'piping through' sockets keeps you update safe. That's a good thing for overall laziness ;)